# Does biblatex-chem automatically format citations in captions for a particular publishers style?

Tags: biblatex, biblatex-chem

I'm looking to insert a citation into the caption using `biblatex` and `biblatex-chem`. I'm trying to follow the citation style of the RSC. When making a reference in an RSC journal within a caption the output I've seen in journals is typically `(adapted from ref. 29.)`. So there is no superscript or parentheses. I can't replicate this using `\autocite{}` or any of the other biblatex citation commands when citing within a `\caption{}`. In the MWE below `\autocite{}` will result in the general citation style used in normal text to be used.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=chem-rsc, articletitle, chaptertitle, language=auto, doi, isbn, defernumbers=false]{biblatex} 
\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes}
\addbibresource{./References/Thesis.bib}    

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{Test.pdf}
\caption{Test test test test \autocite{Test2012}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: no.

Longer answer: `\autocite` is meant to deal with the question of superscript/inline citations, not the complexities of different kinds of citation based on context, publishers style, *etc.* In the case give, I'd go with

```
\caption{Test test test test (adapted from \cite{Test2012}})}
```

(The 'adapted from' or similar may or may not apply to a caption, depending on the situation.)

Comment: Thanks, I had a feeling that was going to be the answer. Do you think it is a good idea for me to remove the square brackets from `\cite{}` or make a `\citecaption{}` command?